# Using React router (v6) why can't I call useNavigate directly?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router

I am new to React JS and a not 100% familiar with TypeScript. As I am learning I have found myself unable to understand an odd 'quirk'.

My code is as follows and my question is "Why do I have to make a const for useNavigate and then call it inside my method?

```
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
...
 const navigate = useNavigate();
  const handleAskQuestionClick = () => {
    navigate('ask');
  };
...
```

What am I missing and why can't it be like this?

```
  const handleAskQuestionClick = () => {
    useNavigate('ask');
  };
```

Comment: `useNavigate` is returning a function that you are assigning to `navigate`. The new function is not equal to the function that returned it.

Comment: @DBS, thank you that makes some sense. So is useNavigate not fully defined until I declare the const 'navigate'? It's odd that gave only a function name but no signature and defined no arguments, yet React knew what to do with my arguments

Answer (score 2):

There are two aspects to explain here.  One is why you cannot call `useNavigate` with an argument and the other is why you cannot call `useNavigate` inside of another function.

`useNavigate` is a React hook.  The [rules of hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html) dictate that you must call all hooks at the top level of your component.  They cannot be called conditionally and they cannot be called inside of a callback like your `handleAskQuestionClick` function.

`useNavigate` needs to be a hook because it internally relies on the `useContext` hook to access your router state through React [context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) (The `BrowserRouter` component is a context provider).  It cannot be just a plain function because then it would be violating the rules of hooks itself.  So `react-router` gives you this `useNavigate` hook which accesses your router state and returns a plain function which is bound to that state.  The function that is returned from `useNavigate` *can* be called in a callback because it is not a hook.

Hooks cannot be called conditionally, so it would not make sense to do something like `uesNavigate('ask')` unless you wanted to navigate to that page immediately when the component is rendered (a redirect).